# Knowing plaintext composition rules, encryption algorithms, and 2 ciphertext blocks, how to find plaintext and keys

Tags: cryptography

Anna wants to send a message with a random arrangement of only 5 words, which are

```
INPUT, GET, HTTP, OUTPUT, POST
```

like

```
INPUTGETOUTPUTPOSTGETHTTPHTTPINPUTGET
```

Each letter occupies 1 byte, and the entire message will be aligned to an integer multiple of **128 bits** by adding 0 at the end of the message.

After getting the message to be sent, Anna divides it into several 128-bit (16 bytes=16 letters) plaintext blocks from beginning to end, like

```
INPUTGETOUTPUTPO, STGETHTTPHTTPINP, UTGET00000000000
```

Randomly pick 2 plaintext blocks P1 and P5, and use a same 128 bit key to get cipher block `C1 = P1 xor key` `C5 = P5 xor key`.

Now suppose I am an adversary. I know all the above **encryption algorithms**, and intercepted 2 **ciphertext blocks CA and CB**, and can determine that 2 ciphertext blocks are generated by **the same key K1**.

The question now is how to decrypt the key and 2 plaintext blocks with the above information.
I have tried many ways, and the ideas are all broken. I am very grateful for the ideas and opinions that have helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version of [two-time pad](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse). I believe this is a contest question so only give you the hint.

X-or the two ciphertext

```
PP = CA x-or CB = PA x-or key x-or PB x-or key = PA x-or PB
```

Now apply one of your limited texts say `OUTPUT` to x-or with this PP by sliding and see that the x-or reveals some other. If you see one, now you get the position of `OUTPUT` in PA. Now you find some in PB too. continue...

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this method, but there is a problem I did not figure out at the end: in the process of sliding, the position of the `OUTPUT` obtained is whether in PA or PB.

Comment: With this two you can never know. Firstly, All you need now, extract the keystream. Say PA, and continue.